# Array Row index function

Tags: powershell

I created a function to find an item in an array so I can update it.

```
  function Get-ArrayRowIndex {
                param(
                    [parameter(mandatory = $true)][array]$Property,
                    [parameter(mandatory = $true)][string]$Value
                )
           
                #Loop through array,incrementing index until value is found. Jordan wrote this and I refined it.
                [int]$index = 0
                while ($index -lt ($Property.count)) {
                    if ($Property[$index] -eq $Value) {
                        break
                    }
                    $index++
                }
                return [int]$index
            }
```

The problem is when the object is not found the function returns the total number of items in the array.
How can I return an error if not found?

Comment: How about, after the loop, you test whether $index equals $Property.count and, if so, return an error?

Comment: You could also use the built-in ```System.Array.IndexOf```

Comment: Good pointer, @adv12, but the caveat is that with strings `.IndexOf()` is case-_sensitive_, whereas PowerShell's operators (such as `-eq`) are case-_insensitive_.

Comment: just for my curiosity ... what do you need the _index_ of an array object for? i usually grab the object itself. the `.Where({})` array method is both fast and rather flexible.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey In my script I am checking the current license counts and then finding people with the wrong license and correcting them this is how the function above comes into play. There might be better ways to do what I am not a pro and lots to learn.

Comment: @dcaz - try taking a look at the speed [and simplicity] of using `$Collection.Where({Filter code here})` gives you. it otta be faster than hunting down an index to use later for accessing the desired object from an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to throw an error in case the value isn't found:

```
function Get-ArrayRowIndex {
                param(
                    [parameter(mandatory = $true)][array]$Property,
                    [parameter(mandatory = $true)][string]$Value
                )
           
                [int]$index = 0
                while ($index -lt ($Property.count)) {
                    if ($Property[$index] -eq $Value) {
                        # Found -> output the value and return (exit) here.
                        return $index 
                    }
                    $index++
                }
                # Getting here means that the value wasn't found.
                throw "'$Value' not found in the given array."
            }
```

Note that you could use the [`[Array]::FindIndex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array.FindIndex) method instead of looping through the array yourself:

```
# Returns the index if found; -1 otherwise.
[Array]::FindIndex(
  $Property, 
  [Predicate[object]] { $Value -eq $args[0] }
)
```

[`[Array].IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array.IndexOf) is another option, but only if case-*sensitive* string comparison is desired (whereas PowerShell's operators, such as `-eq` used above, are case-*insensitive* by default); e.g., `('FOO', 'bar').IndexOf('foo')` yields `-1` (not found) and  `('FOO', 'foo').IndexOf('foo')` yields `1`

Answer (score 3):

Normally a [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.2) loop is a cleaner approach for this:

```
function Get-ArrayRowIndex {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [array] $Property,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Value
    )

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Property.Count; $i++) {
        if ($Property[$i] -eq $Value) {
            return $i
        }
    }

    throw "$Value not found in this array."
}

$arr = 0..10
Get-ArrayRowIndex $arr 4  # => returns 4
Get-ArrayRowIndex $arr 11 # => throws "11 not found in this array."
```

Answer (score 3):

The PowerShell way, using [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string):

```
$Properties = 'One', 'Two', 'Three'
$Value = 'Two'
($Properties | Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern $Value).LineNumber

2
```

**Throwing errors:**

```
$Found = $Properties | Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern $Value
Switch ($Found.Count) {
    0       { Throw "$Value not found" }
    1       { $Found.LineNumber }
    Default { Throw "More than one $Value found" }
}
```

Comment: Great - good job!